# PutMarklogic processor in Nifi

Tags: marklogic, apache-nifi, marklogic-9

I am planning to use Nifi marklogic processor to ingest documents from my s3 bucket .

- Is putMarklogic underneath using MLCP ?
- Can it take all the MLCP options for eg: `aggregate_record_namespace` or `transform_module` or `transform_namespace` or `transform_param`
- If not, what are my options, is it writing custom processor which underneath use  MCLP, as I love the flexibility that MLCP gives :)

As you can see I am planning to call my DHF input flow.. so after looking at the code I think I can set the `transform:ml:inputFlow` and other transform parameters to be prefixed with `trans:`.. is this correct ?

how do I do the mlcp `aggregates` and `aggregate_record_element` and `aggregate_record_namespace`.. as I am loading `.xml.gz` files with multiple xml files.. or my only option is to break them to individual files

Comment: Hi Ravi, putMarkLogic is not using MLCP. The MLCP tool only reads from a filesystem.

Rather, it's using the MarkLogic Java Client API, and in particular the DataMovementManager.

Comment: any thoughts on how to implement aggregates like in `mlcp` using `DataMovementManager.`. basically I want a huge xml into multiple xml records which will be stored as xml documents in ML.. each aggregated xml is  multiple gigs.. `mlcp` handles this.. How to do the same using `DataMonvementManager`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this my writing a custom processor which calls `ContentPump.runCommand`. just fyi, if anyone interested, I had to exclude `log4j` and added `log4j-over-slf4j` so mclp can write the progress logging to `nifi-app.log`.